# Is their a way I can make a workable chess pawn move set using parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, chess

I tried asking this question before but didn't word it all that well so i'am try again.

What I want:

Have a function that takes two parameters, side (dark or white) and number (1-9). In the function itself there's going to be two "if" "functions" (one being 'If', the second being 'if else') both used to checking side and number and runing the any 'special'rules functions their may be (Example: checking where or not it's a pawn's first move so to see whether or not it can move two spaces up). In the If function their would be two more functions to check what side the pawn is on to see if it should move up or down.

Problem:

I ran into a problem where the google console log won't give me any error's and the function would run the If functions. Because of this I unable to know what the problem is.

Code:

```js
var darkPawn1 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn2 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn3 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn4 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn5 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn6 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn7 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn8 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};
var darkPawn9 = {
  stats: 'in',
  firstPawnMove: 'ture'
};


var moveCheck = function(side, number) {
  var pawnInfo = side + 'Pawn' + number;

  var pawnTest = pawnInfo + '.firstPawnMove'

  console.log('log check:' + side + ' ' + number);

  console.log('Pawn Move Check' + ' ' + (pawnInfo + '.firstPawnMove'));

  if (side + 'Pawn' + number + '.firstPawnMove' == 'false') {
    if (side = 'dark') {
      top: '-=' + 50 + 'px'
    }
    else if (side = 'white') {
      top: '+=' + 50 + 'px'
    }
  } else if (side + 'Pawn' + number + '.firstPawnMove' == 'ture') {

    if (side = 'dark') {
      top: '-=' + 100 + 'px',
      side + 'Pawn' + number + '.firstPawnMove' == 'false'
    }
    else if (side = 'white') {
      top: '+=' + 100 + 'px',
      side + 'Pawn' + number + '.firstPawnMove' == 'false'
    }
  }


};

document.getElementById('darkPawnButton1').onclick = moveCheck('dark', '1');
```

```css
#darkChessPlayerId {}

#darkBishop1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkBishop2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkKnight1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkKnight2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkTower1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkTower2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkQueen {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkKing {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn1 {
  top: 270px;
  left: 7px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn4 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn5 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn6 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn7 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn8 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#darkPawn9 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

<!-- White Side Peaces -->#whiteBishop1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whiteBishop2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whiteKnight1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whiteKnight2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whiteTower1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whiteTower2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whiteQueen {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whiteKing {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn4 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn5 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn6 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn7 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn8 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#whitePawn9 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='playFieldId' src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_zJfGdkTGq6U/R6coIhq4e7I/AAAAAAAAAD4/joyxFXtLZRw/s400/chessboard.jpg" />
<button id='boxesAnimationId'>
   Click to run password animation puzzle
  </button>
<button id='darkPawnButton1'>
   test move PAWN
  </button>
<div id='darkChessPlayerId'>
  <img id='darkBishop1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Chess_bdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkBishop2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Chess_bdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkKnight1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Chess_ndt60.png" />
  <img id='darkKnight2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Chess_ndt60.png" />
  <img id='darkTower1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkTower2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkQueen' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Chess_qdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkKing' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Chess_kdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn3' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn4' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn5' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn6' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn7' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn8' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
  <img id='darkPawn9' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png" />
</div>
<div id='whiteChessPlayerId'>
  <img id='whiteBishop1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Chess_blt60.png" />
  <img id='whiteBishop2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Chess_blt60.png" />
  <img id='whiteKnight1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Chess_nlt60.png" />
  <img id='whiteKnight2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Chess_nlt60.png" />
  <img id='whiteTower1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Chess_rlt60.png" />
  <img id='whiteTower2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Chess_rlt60.png" />
  <img id='whiteQueen' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Chess_qlt60.png" />
  <img id='whiteKing' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Chess_klt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn1' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn2' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn3' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn4' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn5' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn6' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn7' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn8' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
  <img id='whitePawn9' src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your `if` conditions do not make sense: they compare two strings which are guaranteed to be always different. Could you add the CSS and HTML you are using and any other JavaScript? Maybe that will clarify what you intended to do.

Comment: you're assigning in the ifs (side = 'dark') + you have typos ( == 'ture') and (side + 'Pawn' + number + '.firstPawnMove' == 'false') can never be true

Comment: Also `top: '-=' + 50 + 'px'` is invalid syntax for a statement.

Comment: It's difficult to know where to begin; you seem to be mixing up objects and code, you're adding things like `'Pawn' + number` multiple times which makes things difficult to reason about, you have dangling expressions that do nothing. It's likely you're getting syntax errors in the console, but that's only part of the problem set. You might want to take a step back and get smaller parts of code working instead of throwing everything on a page at once and wondering what's gone wrong.

Comment: What does 'ture' mean? Did you mean 'true'? It doesn't matter as a string (as long as you are consistent), but it looks strange.

Comment: Imho, it would be simpler to just use a 2 dimensional array to represent the board and fill it with piece objects. The you can define a single function per piece type and that returns the next index they can move to. So the first pawn at index (1,0) would move (+1,+0) to index ( 2, 0 ), a knight could go from ( 0, 2 ) using ( +2, +1 ) to index ( 2, 3 )  or other directions. Then you just rerender the entire board. That will free you up from having to code endless if/else blocks for every single piece seperately and having to manually calculate like position:absolute offsets.

Comment: Indeed, your approach is wrong on many aspects. You need to have a generic solution for a pawn, not have them named separately, not with separate CSS classes (that are just duplicates), not with separate variables, ... Restart this project using arrays, generic CSS classes (one for black, one for white, one for pawn) avoiding duplication.

Comment: @DaveNewton the code was shorter but someone wanted to see more of the code and I was in a rush for something. Also pawn isn’t a variable so I had to turn it into text. The function itself was built in hopes that it only needed a side and number, thus would be able to run with any pawn. Lastly the pawns are objects because I didn’t know how else to check where or not it’s their first move.

Comment: @Shilly thanks, I don’t have my computer with me right know but I try that later and let you know

Comment: @Llamalegs007 I'm not discussing the code you posted here, rather the code you're actually writing: you need to work in smaller chunks at a time because there's a *lot* wrong with the code. Working in smaller bits makes it easier to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your attempt:

- Don't create separate variables for each piece, like `darkPawn1`. Instead place those objects in an array representation of the board.
- `firstPawnMove` gets string value "ture", which is a bit odd (did you intend "true"?). First, you can use booleans in JavaScript (`true` without quotes). Secondly, you'll want to register the current position of each piece, and when you have that, you don't really need 
  `firstPawnMove` anymore, as that can be derived directly from the current position of the pawn and its color.
- Give the piece objects a `color` attribute
- `if (side + 'Pawn' + number + '.firstPawnMove' == 'false') {` is a wrong condition. It will always be false. You probably intended to dynamically access one of the variables, like `darkPawn1`, but as I propose to step away from that variables-concept, this point is no longer relevant
- `if (side = 'dark') {` assigns `'dark'` to `side`. You intended to do `==`.
- `top: '-=' + 50 + 'px'` is not valid JavaScript. You maybe intended to apply some change to some CSS property, but that requires a completely different syntax
- ...several other things that could be improved...

To fix the situation you'd need to start from scratch, as most of your design and code should be modified anyway.

Here is one way to implement a simple chess board. It uses a class for a Piece, a Square and the Board. The Board instance has Square instances, which in turn may have a Piece instance or not.
Some methods allow for rendering, performing moves and getting the move list.

This is of course just a start. You'd have to extend it to other checks, features, user-interaction, ...etc.

```js
class Piece {
    constructor(letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.type = letter.toLowerCase(); // k, q, b, n, r or p
        this.isWhite = letter !== this.type; // Capital <==> white
        this.square = null;
        this.name = { k: "king", q: "queen", b: "bishop", n: "knight", r: "rook", p: "pawn" }[this.type];
    }
    remove() {
        if (this.square) this.square.piece = null;
        this.square = null;
        return this;
    }
    moveTo(square) {
        this.remove();
        if (square.piece) square.piece.remove();
        this.square = square;
        square.piece = this;
        return this;
    }
    moveList() {
        let squares;
        const {square} = this;
        if (!square) return [];
        if (this.type == "p") {
            squares = (square.row === (this.isWhite ? 6 : 1) ? [1,2] : [1]).map(i =>
                square.board.rows[square.row+(this.isWhite ? -i : i)][square.column]
            );
            // TODO: Pawn capturing moves should be generated here
        } else {
            // TODO: Other pieces' moves should be generated here
        }
        return squares;
    }
}

class Square {
    constructor(board, row, column) {
        this.board = board;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.name = "abcdefgh"[column]+(8-row);
        this.piece = null;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Board {
    constructor(arr) {
        this.rows = arr.map((chars, row) => {
            return Array.from(chars, (chr, column) => {
                const square = new Square(this, row, column);
                if (chr !== ".") (new Piece(chr)).moveTo(square);
                this[square.name] = square;
                return square;
            })
        });
    }
    html() {
        return '<table class="chessboard">' + this.rows.map(row => 
            "<tr>" + row.map(({piece}) =>
                '<td><div class="' + (piece ? piece.letter : "") + '"></div></td>'
            ).join`` + "</tr>"
        ).join`` + "</table>";
    }
}

// Create a chess board instance with pieces in their initial positions
const board = new Board([
    "rnbqkbnr",
    "pppppppp",
    "........",
    "........",
    "........",
    "........",
    "PPPPPPPP",
    "RNBQKBNR"
]);
// Show the board
document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = board.html();
// Get the piece object at b2
const piece = board.b2.piece;
// Output info about that piece
console.log(piece.name + " at " + piece.square + " can move to " + piece.moveList());
// Perform a move
piece.moveTo(board.b4);
// Wait a bit and then show board again
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = board.html(), 500);
```

```css
.chessboard { border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
.chessboard td { width: 18px; height: 18px; }
.chessboard tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1),
.chessboard tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) { background: silver; }
.chessboard div { background-size: contain; width: 100%; height: 100% }
.k { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Chess_kdt60.png); }
.q { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Chess_qdt60.png); }
.b { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Chess_bdt60.png); }
.n { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Chess_ndt60.png); }
.r { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png); }
.p { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png); }
.K { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Chess_klt60.png); }
.Q { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Chess_qlt60.png); }
.B { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Chess_blt60.png); }
.N { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Chess_nlt60.png); }
.R { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Chess_rlt60.png); }
.P { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png); }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the well structured feedback. I new to this whole site and will try to improve. The reason the code my looks so bad is mainly due to me and me only doing this coding stuff in my free time. Again thank you, you were a great help and I’ll be sure to let you know if I run into anymore problems!!

Comment: The only thing I would ask is if you give me a better idea of how the code, if not that 100% fine but could someone send me a link to website that could help me. The only reason I ask is because i'm not that great of a coder and manly self teach myself (I still use a few websites).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended for questions about where to find tutorials, etc, but I think you can learn a lot from taking code challenges. Just search with those key words, become member and start coding the easy challenges. Then compare your code with what others submitted. See where you could have done better, ...etc. This way you can potentially improve your skills very fast. Combine with reading some tutorials on specific techniques (like object oriented programming, functional programming, modular programming, ....etc).

Answer (score 0):

This manly works great as a format and helped give me a much better idea of what I should aim for.

```js
class Piece {
    constructor(letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.type = letter.toLowerCase(); // k, q, b, n, r or p
        this.isWhite = letter !== this.type; // Capital <==> white
        this.square = null;
        this.name = { k: "king", q: "queen", b: "bishop", n: "knight", r: "rook", p: "pawn" }[this.type];
    }
    remove() {
        if (this.square) this.square.piece = null;
        this.square = null;
        return this;
    }
    moveTo(square) {
        this.remove();
        if (square.piece) square.piece.remove();
        this.square = square;
        square.piece = this;
        return this;
    }
    moveList() {
        let squares;
        const {square} = this;
        if (!square) return [];
        if (this.type == "p") {
            squares = (square.row === (this.isWhite ? 6 : 1) ? [1,2] : [1]).map(i =>
                square.board.rows[square.row+(this.isWhite ? -i : i)][square.column]
            );
            // TODO: Pawn capturing moves should be generated here
        } else {
            // TODO: Other pieces' moves should be generated here
        }
        return squares;
    }
}

class Square {
    constructor(board, row, column) {
        this.board = board;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.name = "abcdefgh"[column]+(8-row);
        this.piece = null;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Board {
    constructor(arr) {
        this.rows = arr.map((chars, row) => {
            return Array.from(chars, (chr, column) => {
                const square = new Square(this, row, column);
                if (chr !== ".") (new Piece(chr)).moveTo(square);
                this[square.name] = square;
                return square;
            })
        });
    }
    html() {
        return '<table class="chessboard">' + this.rows.map(row => 
            "<tr>" + row.map(({piece}) =>
                '<td><div class="' + (piece ? piece.letter : "") + '"></div></td>'
            ).join`` + "</tr>"
        ).join`` + "</table>";
    }
}

// Create a chess board instance with pieces in their initial positions
const board = new Board([
    "rnbqkbnr",
    "pppppppp",
    "........",
    "........",
    "........",
    "........",
    "PPPPPPPP",
    "RNBQKBNR"
]);
// Show the board
document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = board.html();
// Get the piece object at b2
const piece = board.b2.piece;
// Output info about that piece
console.log(piece.name + " at " + piece.square + " can move to " + piece.moveList());
// Perform a move
piece.moveTo(board.b4);
// Wait a bit and then show board again
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = board.html(), 500);
```

```css
.chessboard { border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
.chessboard td { width: 18px; height: 18px; }
.chessboard tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1),
.chessboard tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) { background: silver; }
.chessboard div { background-size: contain; width: 100%; height: 100% }
.k { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Chess_kdt60.png); }
.q { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Chess_qdt60.png); }
.b { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Chess_bdt60.png); }
.n { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Chess_ndt60.png); }
.r { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png); }
.p { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png); }
.K { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Chess_klt60.png); }
.Q { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Chess_qlt60.png); }
.B { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Chess_blt60.png); }
.N { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Chess_nlt60.png); }
.R { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Chess_rlt60.png); }
.P { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png); }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

```js
class Piece {
    constructor(letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.type = letter.toLowerCase(); // k, q, b, n, r or p
        this.isWhite = letter !== this.type; // Capital <==> white
        this.square = null;
        this.name = { k: "king", q: "queen", b: "bishop", n: "knight", r: "rook", p: "pawn" }[this.type];
    }
    remove() {
        if (this.square) this.square.piece = null;
        this.square = null;
        return this;
    }
    moveTo(square) {
        this.remove();
        if (square.piece) square.piece.remove();
        this.square = square;
        square.piece = this;
        return this;
    }
    moveList() {
        let squares;
        const {square} = this;
        if (!square) return [];
        if (this.type == "p") {
            squares = (square.row === (this.isWhite ? 6 : 1) ? [1,2] : [1]).map(i =>
                square.board.rows[square.row+(this.isWhite ? -i : i)][square.column]
            );
            // TODO: Pawn capturing moves should be generated here
        } else {
            // TODO: Other pieces' moves should be generated here
        }
        return squares;
    }
}

class Square {
    constructor(board, row, column) {
        this.board = board;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.name = "abcdefgh"[column]+(8-row);
        this.piece = null;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Board {
    constructor(arr) {
        this.rows = arr.map((chars, row) => {
            return Array.from(chars, (chr, column) => {
                const square = new Square(this, row, column);
                if (chr !== ".") (new Piece(chr)).moveTo(square);
                this[square.name] = square;
                return square;
            })
        });
    }
    html() {
        return '<table class="chessboard">' + this.rows.map(row => 
            "<tr>" + row.map(({piece}) =>
                '<td><div class="' + (piece ? piece.letter : "") + '"></div></td>'
            ).join`` + "</tr>"
        ).join`` + "</table>";
    }
}

// Create a chess board instance with pieces in their initial positions
const board = new Board([
    "rnbqkbnr",
    "pppppppp",
    "........",
    "........",
    "........",
    "........",
    "PPPPPPPP",
    "RNBQKBNR"
]);
// Show the board
document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = board.html();
// Get the piece object at b2
const piece = board.b2.piece;
// Output info about that piece
console.log(piece.name + " at " + piece.square + " can move to " + piece.moveList());
// Perform a move
piece.moveTo(board.b4);
// Wait a bit and then show board again
setTimeout(() => document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = board.html(), 500);
```

```css
.chessboard { border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }
.chessboard td { width: 18px; height: 18px; }
.chessboard tr:nth-child(2n) td:nth-child(2n+1),
.chessboard tr:nth-child(2n+1) td:nth-child(2n) { background: silver; }
.chessboard div { background-size: contain; width: 100%; height: 100% }
.k { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Chess_kdt60.png); }
.q { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Chess_qdt60.png); }
.b { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Chess_bdt60.png); }
.n { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Chess_ndt60.png); }
.r { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png); }
.p { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Chess_pdt60.png); }
.K { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Chess_klt60.png); }
.Q { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Chess_qlt60.png); }
.B { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Chess_blt60.png); }
.N { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Chess_nlt60.png); }
.R { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/Chess_rlt60.png); }
.P { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Chess_plt60.png); }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```